# SQL IF NOT EXISTS INSERT ELSE UPDATE on mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, not-exists

I am trying to do a `if not exist insert else update`, however it's telling me there's an issue with insert:

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM vendor_publication_daily_draws WHERE pub_id = '73609850' AND paper_code = 'STSC') THEN INSERT INTO vendor_publication_daily_draws (`alouette.acct`, month, year, paper_code, pub_id, `01`) VALUES ('97', '08', '2022', 'STSC', '73609850', '5'); ELSE UPDATE vendor_publication_daily_draws SET `01` = '5' WHERE `alouette.acct` = '97' AND (pub_id = '73609850' OR pub_id = '73609850') AND paper_code = 'STSC' AND month = '08' AND year = '2022'; failed :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? The table does not have a usable unique key as the data is very repetitive.

This is what I have:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT * FROM vendor_publication_daily_draws 
               WHERE pub_id = '73609850' AND paper_code = 'STSC') 
THEN
INSERT INTO vendor_publication_daily_draws (`alouette.acct`, month, year, paper_code, pub_id, `01`) 
VALUES ('97', '08', '2022', 'STSC', '73609850', '5') 
ELSE 
UPDATE vendor_publication_daily_draws 
SET `01` = '5' 
WHERE `alouette.acct` = '97' 
AND (pub_id = '73609850' OR pub_id = '73609850') 
AND paper_code = 'STSC' 
AND month = '08' 
AND year = '2022';
```

I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to find a working example that matches my needs.

Comment: Please show us the actual error message.

Comment: you can't do that in an sql, only in a procedures or functions but even then the syntax is wrong

Comment: @nbk Can you elaborate a little more? Or do you have an idea how I could do this in a query?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: Just use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361368)

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you have an `UNIQUE INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` on (pub_id ,paper_code )

```
INSERT INTO vendor_publication_daily_draws (`alouette.acct`, month, year, paper_code, pub_id, `01`) 
VALUES ('97', '08', '2022', 'STSC', '73609850', '5') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE month=VALUES(month),`alouette.acct` = VALUES(`alouette.acct`)
  ,year = VALUES(year),`01` = VALUES(`01`)
```

there is also the possibility of a dynamic approach, which i  also  can provide if abouve fails.

Comment: I think the main problem is, I don't have a useable primary_key... I have to basically look up the data, see if it's already there and either update or insert.